# Как исправить пересечение данных в Printf?

Tags: c, opencl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понимаю, как описать проблему. При использовании printf у меня данные показываются криво. Если посмотреть на картинку - Значение Start - 10... Это значение должно быть у Date в последнем %d. Он не вывел значение, а написал лишь %d. Скорее всего не хватает памяти и данные как-то пересекаются. Кто сталкивался с подобным, есть какие-то решения, кроме как изменить код, чтобы выделял меньше памяти? По сути, данный код вызывается всего лишь 1 раз со значением Start = 0. Но у меня Start показывается на каждой итерации.

```
printf("Start - %d", start);
if (start == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2998; i++)
    {
        printf("Date - %d:%d;%d:%d:%d; ", date[i].hour, date[i].minute, date[i].day, date[i].month, date[i].year);
    }
}
else
{
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = start; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("NEW Date - %d:%d;%d:%d:%d; ", date[i].hour, date[i].minute, date[i].day, date[i].month, date[i].year);
        j++;
        if (j == 3000)
            return;
    }
}
```

Добавил простой пример вывода данных в консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показать код. Без кода ничего нельзя сказать.

Comment: В ответ на вопрос "доктор, у меня что-то болит" ответ один - "выпейте какое-то лекарство"... Что именно болит у вас? Получить вашу проблему можно десятком способов - как узнать, на что способны конкретно вы?...

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил код, не знаю, чем он сможет помочь, но вот

Comment: @Harry извините за некорректность, добавил код. Просто он максимально прост, поэтому думал не писать

Comment: Попробуйте %i. Он аналогичен %d. Да... странный глюк.

Comment: @nick_n_a но нет, он выводит тоже самое.. Не знаю, возможно где-то и правда проблема с памятью, буду сейчас ломать голову..

Comment: Может тупой совет (но извините). Попробуйте разбить вывод на два вызова printf. А так еще бы посмотреть на обьявление структуры и массива...

Comment: У вас ф-ция sprintf - есть? Может проще будет через sprintf - разбить ф-цию на две части? У вас ПО для чипа? Возможно ваш printf не хавает пять параметров?

Comment: Похоже, где-то какие-то проблемы с памятью. Что-то не туда пишется, например. Надо смотреть весь код...

Comment: @Harry ну вот да, проблема скорее всего там, сейчас буду узнавать, как проверить, сколько мне памяти вообще выделяется и не переполнил ли я её

Comment: @nick_n_a с помощью sprintf не получится, С99 не поддерживает данную функцию..

Comment: А вообще char-массивом пользоваться можно? Данная задача через char-массив делается - тупо 16 попарно одинаковых строк. Типа `с[0] = month / 10 + 48; Типа с[1] = month % 10 + 48;`

Comment: C99 должен поддерживать sprintf. Разве что т.к. вы пишите под opencl то могу быть ограничения.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну там по сути у меня массив типа Date, структура с int значениями дня, часа и т п. И я по очереди перебираю.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну там скорее не задача, а я пытаюсь вывести свои данные, расчеты я не вставлял после этого. Да и проблема даже не в данных, они все верны. Если без printf всё делать, то все расчеты верны, но как только я добавляю printf - он выводит хрен знает что в консоль.

Comment: @Fresto - Либо Вы показываете не весь код печати, либо Вы показываете не тот код! В приведённом коде отсутствуют символы перевода строки (\n) в операторах *printf()*. Тем не менее - перевод строки (судя по скриншоту) выполняется... Как то это странно!

Comment: @Sergey я же подписал еще, что пишу под OpenCL, так что я (\n) не ставлю, он автоматически переходит на другую строку. В итоге ошибка в памяти, что устройству не хватает памяти. Буду думать над другой реализацией программы, чтобы всё было хорошо

Comment: Вот пример с официального сайта (https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl22-reference-guide.pdf) про *printf()*: *loat4  f = float4(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);uchar4 uc = uchar4(0xFA, 0xFB, 0xFC, 0xFD);printf(“f4 = %2.2v4hlf\n”, f);printf(“uc = %#v4hhx\n”, uc);* Символы перевода строки на месте...

Comment: @Sergey добавил для вас пример в свой пост. Там вся функцию kernel, простой цикл и вывод с помощью printf значения i